# The command "zypper --non-interactive --force-resolution update" fails with error: Unknown option '--force-resolution'

Tags: suse, zypper

As per the zypper manual https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_%28plain%29, the parameter "--force-resolution" is present in the zypper update command but when I am trying to use this parameter in the command, I am getting the following error:
Unknown option '--force-resolution'

Is this parameter recently removed? I am using SUSE 12 SP5

Answer (score 0):

Order matters, try `zypper --non-interactive update --force-resolution`.

The way you have it, the switch applies to the core `zypper` command, however, it actually applies to `update`.